# Execution of JavaScript on save post

Tags: jquery, javascript, save-post, autosave

I got stuck with one problem, can somebody please help.. :)
I would like to execute custom JavaScript function before post is saved, and i can't find how to do that. 
Something like JavaScript version of save_post action hook :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like shown below, as suggested by @gyo and done by @Howdy_McGee in his [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176968/16929).

```
function admin_queue( $hook ) {
    global $post; 
    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        if ( 'targeted-posttype' === $post->post_type ) { 
            wp_enqueue_script( 
                'custom-title-here', 
                bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/scripts/custom-script.js', 
                'jquery', 
                '', 
                true 
            );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_queue' );
```

Comment: I need it to execute on page before save and reloading, so something like: on click preventDefault execute my function and then continue where interruption was..

Comment: In both solutions javascript will be executed when post is saved but at that point DOM will not be avaliable.. I need this function to combine several user inputs and add it into content.

Comment: Thank you for help, i will use metabox and do all combination in php. Thank you for idea!

Comment: This answer also shows how to hook the saving action with Javascript: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176968/16929

Comment: How can this solution possibly work? As noted by @abdom, the DOM is not available anymore when the hook is triggered. The generated JS is printed for nothing. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It can't, I replaced it with the suggested working solution. @philippe_b

Comment: This solution lacks the content of `custom-script.js`, which is not trivial: you need to know the `id` of the form. Plus, the original solution of @Howdy_McGee doesn't work on my WP 4.6.1 (look for my comment)

Comment: @philippe_b The general rule is »*one problem per question*«, so I'm not feeling the obligation to add some random, not requested javascript file.