# How to execute a javascript function just before saving a woocommerce post or a post?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am working on this project and I am trying to execute a jquery or javascript just before saving the post,
I have tried the following:

```
 function do_something_with_a_post($id) {

 <script>alert('hello');</script>
 }
 add_action('pre_post_update', 'do_something_with_a_post');
```

but it gives a php error... I am really unsure on how to do this.

Does anyone has an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't place `javascript` inside a php function and expect it to run. Javascript happens in browser, and should be triggered by some user-related event (think clicks, browsing, scrolling, etc). Php happens server side. You need to use php in that function.

Comment: Did you see wp_enqueue_scripts http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You *could* place javascript in a PHP function and expect it to run such as [`admin_head`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head) or the likes, it just needs to be escaped properly with ending PHP tags `?> <script> alert( 'here' ); </script> <?php` ( or even echoed out really ). That being said, since this hook does run *behind the scenes* you would never see the alert.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Technically you're right. But why would anyone want to run javascript during php execution **and not inside a webpage**? Can you give me a **useful** example?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You're right, during a hook like `save_post` the JS is useless because it's being run *behind the scenes*, but JS could useful in other PHP functions such as `admin_head` or `admin_footer`. You may want to do this just for testing purposes ( versus creating a separate script file *then* enqueueing it ) or maybe it's such a small piece of code that it doesn't necessarily need it's own script ( initializing a datepicker to a css class ). I'm not suggesting it's a good practice to get into I just wanted correct the statement that it *can't* be done inside a PHP function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javascript you have will never run because WordPress is running this in the background as purely PHP, there is HTML to associate with your Javascript. If we look at the documentation on the [`pre_post_update` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_post_update) it states:

> Called just before $wpdb->update()

Which is run purely in PHP. If it's easier to see what I mean, here's the [full code on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3335), if you scroll the top top you'll notice there's no HTML Document associated to it. I believe what you need is what @Brad Dalton suggested and to create your own script and enqueue it on your post-type ( which if dealing with WooCommerce would be `product` ).

For example, we can add this to our `functions.php` file:

```
/** Admin Enqueue **/
function admin_queue( $hook ) {
    global $post; 

    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        if ( 'product' === $post->post_type ) { 
            wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-title-here', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/scripts/custom-script.js', 'jquery', '', true );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_queue' );
```

For more information on how to use [`wp_enqueue_script`, View Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). Depending on what you're trying to do you could run your JS on the submission of the form:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '#post' ).submit( function( e ) {
        alert( 'Stopping Form From Submitting.' );
        return false;
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Maybe this is new, but at least WP 4.6.1 declares the form with `submit` as its `name` attribute, making this solution fails with message `theForm.submit is not a function` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript#answer-834197). A workaround is to use `on`. For example: `$(document).on('submit', postForm, function() {...});`

Comment: @philippe_b Thanks, it looks like there was an error in the initial script, I've tested it and fixed it for 4.6.1